# How to match specific number from text - Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

```
    id="profile_photo_link" href="/photo83085640_283973341" onclick="return showPhoto('83085640_283973341', 'album8308564
    0_0/rev', 

{temp:{base:&quot;http://cs301701.vk.me/v301701640/&quot;,x_:[&quot;181d/N_1czOIgH0s&quot;,556,313]},

jumpTo:
    {z: 'albums83085640'}}, event)">

<img width="200" height="205" src="http://cs301701.vk.me/v301701640/4a03/mfKV3wOhrqU.jpg
    " alt="Сергей On-line Консультации Василюк">
```

How to match this(83085640) number from text above by ruby regex ? The Start of regex must be after showPhoto(' text and ends at this point _ after numbers

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? Here's a great site for debugging regexes: http://rubular.com

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/NqHzS8sq5h

Comment: The worlds showPhoto(' must not include in the output, this is only starting point

Comment: Google: regex matching group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to do the following:

```
my_text = "showPhoto('83085640_283973341',";    #Input string. I'm only using a part of it here for convenience.
pat = /showPhoto\('(\d*)_/;    #The Regexp pattern as per your requirements.

puts(pat.match(my_text)[1]);
```

Output:

```
83085640
```